# nil value instead of form value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a page index of `Beer Receipe` which also is supposed to display the ratings/comments. I've inserted a couple in `rails c`, and it displays fine on the `Beer Receipe` page. But when I try to create the rating on the form itself, both the star and comment comes up blank on the form, and when I look in the rails c, it shows `nil` value. Why?

Have three models: Beer_Receipe, Ingredient, & Rating

This is the schema:

```
  create_table "beer_receipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "style"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "ratable_type"
    t.integer  "ratable_id"
    t.integer  "stars"
    t.text     "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

Their associations are:

```
class BeerReceipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings, as: :ratable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings, as: :ratable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ratable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This is the `Beer Receipe Index`

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h2>Beer Receipe Index</h2>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @beer_receipe.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Style:</strong>
  <%= @beer_receipe.style %>
</p>

<h2>Ratings</h2>
<%= render @beer_receipe.ratings %>

<h2>Add Ratings</h2>
<%= render 'ratings/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_beer_receipe_path(@beer_receipe) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', beer_receipes_path %>
```

This is the `_form.html.erb` page

```
<%= form_for([@beer_receipe, @beer_receipe.ratings.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :stars %><br>
        <%= f.select :stars, (0..10) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :comments %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :comments %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
```

And lastly, but not least, Ratings Controller

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @beer_receipe = BeerReceipe.find(params[:beer_receipe_id])
    @rating = @beer_receipe.ratings.create(rating_params)
    #redirect_to beer_receipe_path(@beer_receipe)
  end

  def destroy 
    @beer_receipe = BeerReceipe.find(params[:beer_receipe_id])
    @rating = @beer_receipe.ratings.find(params[:id])
    @rating.destroy
    redirect_to beer_receipe_path(@rating)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private 

    def rating_params
        params.require(:rating).permit(:star, :comment)
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

```
Started POST "/beer_receipes/1/ratings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 15:14:43 -0700
Processing by RatingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3kilQgA3tZ0ZxsfuRY4LKFkNl3+oL1x9zRT2/EccDeM0b+6a1NuHgo6cHaYOqBJMd6s4dduID06i5oTvcBisTw==", "rating"=>{"stars"=>"6", "comments"=>"testing .."}, "commit"=>"Create Rating", "beer_receipe_id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mBeerReceipe Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "beer_receipes".* FROM "beer_receipes" WHERE "beer_receipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: stars, comments
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "ratings" ("ratable_id", "ratable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["ratable_id", 1], ["ratable_type", "BeerReceipe"], ["created_at", "2016-04-01 22:14:43.982989"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-01 22:14:43.982989"]]
  [1m[36m (38.6ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendered ratings/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 437ms (Views: 351.6ms | ActiveRecord: 40.8ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 15:16:03 -0700
Processing by BeerReceipesController#index as HTML
  [1m[35mBeerReceipe Load (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "beer_receipes".* FROM "beer_receipes"
  Rendered beer_receipes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 686ms (Views: 668.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/beer_receipes/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 15:16:06 -0700
Processing by BeerReceipesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mBeerReceipe Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "beer_receipes".* FROM "beer_receipes" WHERE "beer_receipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[35mRating Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."ratable_id" = ? AND "ratings"."ratable_type" = ?  [["ratable_id", 2], ["ratable_type", "BeerReceipe"]]
  Rendered ratings/_rating.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered ratings/_form.html.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered beer_receipes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (90.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 134.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started POST "/beer_receipes/2/ratings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 15:16:11 -0700
Processing by RatingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WmwvDG+a/YsgGKpOGtlxQLUCNjyc/+y3lhab5ZO9WPCwS2TUu3bPlLdCcAZR/2gkm6SZNu9Yv4T55On2pLn5XA==", "rating"=>{"stars"=>"3", "comments"=>"sdfsdf"}, "commit"=>"Create Rating", "beer_receipe_id"=>"2"}
  Rendered ratings/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 101.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you share the application logs?

Comment: Could you `puts params.inspect` inside the create action to see what's coming through?

Comment: @toddmetheny, you mean in `ratings_controller`?

Comment: yes please. I'd like to see the params hash.

Comment: @MarceloRisoli, just added the last bits of the development log. Not the entirety of it since it's rather long.

Comment: @toddmetheny, um ... I put it in ratings_controller create action .. .but now when I try to create a rating, it goes straight to `http://localhost:3000/beer_receipes/2/ratings` ... it was doing that before `puts params.inspect` not sure why it's doing that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your ratings controller create action:

```
@rating = Rating.new(stars: params[:rating][:star], comments: params[:rating][:comments], ratable_id: params[:beer_recipe_id])

if @rating.save
  puts "huzzah!"
end
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: this is what I get when I tried to create a rating after pasting your code above: `/beerfulPolymorphic/app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_if, expecting ')' if @rating.save ^`

Comment: it's in reference to this line: `if @rating.save`

Comment: I forgot to close parens in the previous line. fixed. Add a `)` to the rating def line and it should work. @user27307254534534534543675765

Comment: this is what I get now: `
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in RatingsController#create
unknown attribute 'star' for Rating.`

Comment: does ratings table not have a `star`? do you have pending migrations? check your schema to make sure star is there.

Comment: i've pasted the schema in the post above earlier. it has `stars` and `comments` ...

Comment: ah--it's the way you're passing the parameters that's causing them to read as unpermitted.

Comment: um, say what? =) English, please?

Comment: the form should actually be a nested form for ratings if you're using this action...right now it's nested with @beer first

Comment: i got it. i had to pluralize the stars and comments in the `ratings_params`

Comment: go ahead and still fill in the answer. i'll accept it. it's really due to you that i even noticed that in the first place. thank you!

Comment: hey ... i tried your edit just now ... and this is what I got ...`
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in RatingsController#create
unknown attribute 'beer_receipe_id' for Rating.`

Comment: needs to be `ratable_id` with a ratable type of beer recipe

Comment: never mind my previous comment. Ratings show up. that was the whole point of this question. Thank you! Will create questions for other issues.